# Django - filtering on foreign key usin an attribut

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter, django-filters

i have 2 foreingkey , one from the User and the other one from Device.

```
class checkn(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True,on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    devices = models.ForeignKey(Device, null=True,on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    ch = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
```

he's using the Device ID for the search and i want to use the IP adresse :
[image]

this is the device model :

```
class Device(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=dtype, null=True)
    ipadress = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

any advices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ip address to show in the search field do

```
class Device(models.Model):
   ...
   def __str__(self):
      return self.ipaddress
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters like this

```
query = checkn.objects.filter(devices__ipadress=user_input_ipadress_here)
```

So if you want to access som ForeignKeys attributes, you can jut separe it with double underscore like so :

> ModelAttributeName__AttributeName